# Can I Launch Microsoft Edge with Emulation turned on for mobile devices via automation (ie Selenium or the like)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Can I launch Microsoft Edge with Emulation turned on for mobile devices via automation such as Selenium so that I can automation mobile testing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we're currently able to set Emulation options that are usually available via F12.

That said, you might be able to work around the issue by using set window size commands within webdriver?